# CMake can't find C++ compiler in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everyone, I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 and got this message below while trying to create a catkin workspace:

```
bruna@bruna-laptop ~/catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/bruna/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/bruna/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/bruna/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/bruna/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/bruna/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/bruna/catkin_ws/build/test_results
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.16
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bruna/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bruna/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I am a new user, so I dont know what I did here.
Anyone can help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221727/cmake-can%27t-find-c++-compiler-in-linux-mint/) by [BrunaGarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25206/brunagarcia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-30**:
Also: please tell us how you installed ROS (which tutorial(s) did you follow, if any) and which version it is.

**Comment by [BrunaGarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25206/brunagarcia/) on 2015-11-30**:
ROS indigo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From:

> ```
> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
> ```

and:

> ```
> CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
> ```

I would say you don't have any C++ compiler installed.

can you try something like `which g++` and append the output to your original question?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrunaGarcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25206/brunagarcia/) on 2015-11-30**:
Yeah, you're right! Now it works.
Followed this to solve the problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers

Thank you!